# Placing buttons adjacent to each other inside a frame using tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as tkmb

# globals

buttons = {}
root = None   

# Root Window
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('buttons')

# connect button
comButtonFrame = tk.Frame(root)
label = tk.Label(comButtonFrame, text = 'Open Connection')
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
comPortButtonConnect = tk.Button(comButtonFrame, text='Connect', width=10)
buttons['connect']=comPortButtonConnect

# disconnect button
comPortButtonDisconnect = tk.Button(comButtonFrame, text='Disconnect', width=10)
buttons['disconnect'] = comPortButtonDisconnect


# Program device button
comPortButtonProgram = tk.Button(comButtonFrame, text='Program',width=10)
buttons['program'] = comPortButtonProgram


# display button in a grid
comPortButtonConnect.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
comPortButtonDisconnect.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
comPortButtonProgram.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
comButtonFrame.pack(anchor=tk.W, fill=None, side=tk.TOP, pady=30)

w = root.winfo_width() + 600   # width for the Tk root
h = root.winfo_height() + 830 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window top left corner
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

# set the dimensions of the window
# and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
# start in fullscreen mode
# root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
# run GUI
root.mainloop()
```

I am not able to get the disconnect and program buttons to be closer to each other. Any suggestions on how that can be done ? This is what it looks like right now. In the code I posted, ignore the callbacks. You can delete the option to get it to run. Its not relevant since I only want to know how to fix the display.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As in complete code that we can copy and run that displays your problem.

Comment: Done. Ignore the callback lines.

Comment: This code is not Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. I cannot run this in the Python IDLE. Please can you amend so that we can actually run the code you are asking about.

Comment: can you now ? Sorry for the hassle